# does linux 3.7.1 support ext2?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm conducting a lab recently and I just found that linux 3.7.1 has no /include/linux/magic.h.  Does this mean that linux 3.7.1 not support ext2? If I really need to do some modification in the magic.h, for example, change the `#define EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC 0xEF53` to `#define EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC 0X6666`, and I have another file which need this header file, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check:

```
include/uapi/linux/magic.h
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and neat answer. I tried to search the `magic.h` but failed. But anyway, I found it according to your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

Linux 3.7.1 definitely supports ext2. The Linux kernel has supported ext2 since shortly after its release in early 1993, and support has never been removed. It *is* possible to build a working Linux kernel that doesn't support ext2, but that wouldn't remove it from the headers.

Depending on what distribution you're using, that file (and other Linux) headers may be elsewhere. Icarus3's answer may solve your problem; otherwise, remember that:

1. It's possible to have the Linux headers installed in multiple places.
2. The most common place for them to be installed automatically is `/usr/include/linux`.
3. Someone else installed them *manually* on this system, they may have installed them to `/usr/local/include/linux`.

Such files are usually located in a `linux` subdirectory of an `include` directory. So you could look in those places, starting in `/usr/include/linux`.

If that doesn't help, *and* you *have* a `uapi` subdirectory of an `include` directory, [Icarus3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919896/icarus3) may solve your problem.

Assuming you're using a distribution that *has* a package manager, try using the distro-specific search utilities (which usually exist on the web even if you cannot do this from the local machine) to find out what packages provide files called `magic.h`.

Comment: Thank youo very much. But I'm just a freshman to linux. And I just follow some instruction to do the lab. I thought about using `/usr/include/linux/magic.h`, but I don't know how to do it. But anyway, your answer convinced my thought. Maybe I can try it later after I finish the lab. Thanks a lot.